# Please help me understand : For Loop Ending Sub

Tags: excel, vba

My intern and I wrote a block of VBA that circles through a data set and cleans out rows we do not want before analysis is applied. The loop worked on one day and then the next day it would do the strangest thing: it would appear to execute, but then end the sub and not execute any code after it. We found a solution, which I believe is just better coding in general, that worked, but I don't understand why the original code didn't work and why it was ending the sub. It didn't spit out any errors, it just pretended like it was done and no amount of breaks would stop it mid execution.

Here is the broken block-

```
LastRow = wb_Audit.Sheets("Data Sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, "AN").End(xlUp).Row
For iRow = 2 To LastRow
        If wb_Audit.Sheets("Data Sheet").Cells(iRow, "AQ").Value = "Dead Deal" Then
           wb_Audit.Worksheets("Data Sheet").Range("AM" & iRow & ":AW" & iRow).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
            iRow = iRow - 1
            LastRow = LastRow - 1
            If iRow > LastRow Then End
            Else: End If
        If wb_Audit.Sheets("Data Sheet").Cells(iRow, "AQ").Value = "Closed" Then
           wb_Audit.Worksheets("Data Sheet").Range("AM" & iRow & ":AW" & iRow).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
            iRow = iRow - 1
            LastRow = LastRow - 1
            If iRow > LastRow Then End
            Else: End If
        If wb_Audit.Sheets("Data Sheet").Cells(iRow, "AM").Value = "" Then
           wb_Audit.Worksheets("Data Sheet").Range("AM" & iRow & ":AW" & iRow).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
            iRow = iRow - 1
            LastRow = LastRow - 1
            If iRow > LastRow Then End
            Else: End If
        If wb_Audit.Sheets("Data Sheet").Cells(iRow, "AM").Value = "HOLD" Then
           wb_Audit.Worksheets("Data Sheet").Range("AM" & iRow & ":AW" & iRow).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
            iRow = iRow - 1
            LastRow = LastRow - 1
            If iRow > LastRow Then End
            Else: End If
    Next iRow
```

Here is the block that we replaced this with that works fine now.

```
 For iRow = 2 To LastRow
        If iRow > LastRow Then Exit For
        If wb_Audit.Sheets("Data Sheet").Cells(iRow, "AQ").Value = "Dead Deal" Then
           wb_Audit.Worksheets("Data Sheet").Range("AM" & iRow & ":AW" & iRow).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
            iRow = iRow - 1
            LastRow = LastRow - 1
        Else: End If
        If wb_Audit.Sheets("Data Sheet").Cells(iRow, "AQ").Value = "Closed" Then
           wb_Audit.Worksheets("Data Sheet").Range("AM" & iRow & ":AW" & iRow).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
            iRow = iRow - 1
            LastRow = LastRow - 1
        Else: End If
        If wb_Audit.Sheets("Data Sheet").Cells(iRow, "AM").Value = "" Then
           wb_Audit.Worksheets("Data Sheet").Range("AM" & iRow & ":AW" & iRow).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
            iRow = iRow - 1
            LastRow = LastRow - 1
        Else: End If
        If wb_Audit.Sheets("Data Sheet").Cells(iRow, "AM").Value = "HOLD" Then
           wb_Audit.Worksheets("Data Sheet").Range("AM" & iRow & ":AW" & iRow).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
            iRow = iRow - 1
            LastRow = LastRow - 1
        Else: End If
    Next iRow
```

We have working code, I just want to understand what was wrong with the first block.

Comment: I got a feeling you can shorten this a lot if you go `For iRow = LastRow To 2 Step -1`

Comment: You could simplify your code by factoring `wb_Audit.Sheets("Data Sheet")`. BTW, why do you sometime use `wb_Audit.Sheets("Data Sheet")` and other times `wb_Audit.Worksheets("Data Sheet")`?
`Else: End If` Just remove `Else:`, it can only confuse people.

Comment: @VincentG I get an unpaired if error when I used just End If. Adding the Else seemed to fix that. As for the worksheets v sheets, idk I wrote the original block and the intern filled in the other three. I don't think it effects anything in this case.

Comment: No, you shouldn't have unpaired If error with just the code you posted and removing the `Else:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the help page for the [End statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/end-statement):

> The End statement stops code execution abruptly, without invoking the
>   Unload, QueryUnload, or Terminate event, or any other Visual Basic
>   code

`If iRow > LastRow Then End` will terminate the macro immediately if `iRow > LastRow` when we reach this line. Any code after the `For iRow = 2 To LastRow` loop won't ever be executed because the macro will have terminated.

Rather than using `End`, use `Exit For` if all you want to do is to break out of the `For` loop

Comment: I thought this was the cause, but when we originally wrote the code, it was working. The fixed block uses the better Exit For. I just wanted to understand if there was anything obvious to explain why it used to work but suddenly stopped working.

Answer (score 3):

Just to show you an alternative to your code:

```
Sub NewSub()

Dim lr As Long, irow As Long
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Sheet")
    lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, "AN").End(xlUp).Row
    For irow = lr To 2 Step -1
        If .Cells(irow, "AQ").Value = "Dead Deal" Or .Cells(irow, "AQ").Value = "Closed" Or .Cells(irow, "AM").Value = "" Or .Cells(irow, "AM").Value = "HOLD" Then
            .Range("AM" & irow & ":AW" & irow).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
        End If
    Next irow
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This is very nice, thank you. What does the -1 in the For loop specifically mean?

Comment: @ARL It means you are counting from highest to lowest ie. incrementing by -1 or decrementing by 1

Comment: @Dean Ah! So you start at the bottom and work up, which eliminates the need for the irow = irow -1 part. That's clever and useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue was not deleting from the bottom up, and trying to work around the issues you were encountering. What happens when you delete from top to bottom is; when you test a row and then delete the data, the row below shifts into the current row, your loop then moves to the next row down, causing you to skip the row that shifted up. Like JvdV shows you can combine all your criteria into one `If` statement. Your code can be shortened a lot...

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, lastRow As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Sheet") 'Or Workbooks("wb_Audit").Sheets("Data Sheet")

lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "AN").End(xlUp).Row

For iRow = lastRow To 2 Step -1  'when deleting rows you need to start from the bottom
    If ws.Cells(iRow, "AQ").Value = "Dead Deal" Or ws.Cells(iRow, "AQ").Value = "Closed" Or _
    ws.Cells(iRow, "AM").Value = "" Or ws.Cells(iRow, "AM").Value = "HOLD" Then
    ws.Range("AM" & iRow & ":AW" & iRow).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
Next iRow
```

Comment: the iRow = iRow - 1 part of each block dealt with the shifted row. Thank you for the shortened block, i'll use it for reference in the future.